# How Razor Pages work with @namespace when there are sub folders in Pages folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I created a project named `RazorPageMovie` with the Razor Page template where I got a folder named `Pages` for free. Then I added a sub folder named `Movies` to `Pages` folder and added `Index.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml.cs`  to `Movies` folder.

I opened `_ViewImports.cshtml` and I found the following code:

```
@using RazorPageMovie
@namespace RazorPageMovie.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I know that `_ViewImports.cshtml` will be imported for each page and 
the code behind `Index.cshtml.cs` of `Pages/Movies/Index.cshtml` defines its own namespace `RazorPageMovie.Pages.Movies`.

My question is:

How can  `Pages/Movies/Index.cshmtl` work *without* problem  recall that we only let `_ViewImport.cshtml` add `@namespace RazorPageMovie.Pages` to  `Pages/Movies/Index.cshmtl` but we have not explicitly added  `@namespace RazorPageMovie.Pages.Movies` to `Pages/Movies/Index.cshmtl` yet?

It seems to me that `@namespace RazorPageMovie.Pages.Movies` is passed to `Pages/Movies/Index.cshtml` silently.